# Как передать массив в функцию класса? пытался с помощью указателей, но как-то не очень

Tags: c++, указатели

```
    class VectorClass {
    private:
        double   a[3], b[3] = { 4,5,6 };

    public:



        void print(int date_x, int date_y, int date_z) {

            unsigned long d = sqrt(pow(date_x, 2) + pow(date_y, 2) + pow(date_z, 2));
            double xcos = date_x / d;
            double ycos = date_y / d;
            double zcos = date_z / d;
            cout << "lenght |d| =" << d << endl;
            cout << "cos A=" << "(" << xcos << ";" << ycos << ";" << zcos << ")" << endl;
            cout << "(x,y,z)=" << "(" << date_x << "," << date_y << "," << date_z << ")" << endl;
        }


        double peregryzka(int date_x, int date_y, int date_z) {

            long ab = date_x * 4 + date_y * 5 + date_z * 6;
            return ab;
            a[1] = date_x;
            a[2] = date_y;
            a[3] = date_z;


        }
        int peregryzka(int date_x, int date_y, int date_z, int  c) {
            c = date_y * 6 - date_z * 5 - date_x * 6 - date_z * 4 + date_x * 5 - 4 * date_y;
            return c;
        }
          int peregryzka(ptr) {

            for (int i = 1;i = 3;i++) {
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
                return c[i];
            }


        }
    };
int main()
{

    VectorClass coordinates;

    int x, y, z, VM = 1, scal = 1;

    int *ptr ;
     int c[] = { x,y,z };
     ptr = c;

    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    cin >> z;


    coordinates.print(x, y, z);
    scal = coordinates.peregryzka(x, y, z);
    VM = coordinates.peregryzka(x, y, z, VM);
    std::cout << "scal=" << scal << endl;
    std::cout << "VM=" << VM << endl;
    std::cout << "sum="<< coordinates.peregryzka(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

> функция в классе

```
int peregryzka(ptr) {

            for (int i = 1;i = 3;i++) {
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
                return c[i];
            }
```

> в мейне

```
int *ptr ;
         int c[] = { x,y,z };
         ptr = c;
    std::cout << "sum="<< coordinates.peregryzka(ptr);
```

Comment: Цель всей работы - это сложение, скалярное и векторное умножение векторов с помощью методов классов

Comment: `int peregryzka(int* ptr)` если массив интовый. Ты в классе описываешь непонятно что. Нет такого типа данных `ptr`. Нужно показать, что сюда пойдёт указатель `int* ptr`. Ну а по скольку имя массива это адрес его первого элемента, то можно просто имя передать в вызове.

Answer (score 1):

int peregryzka(int *ptr) {...}
Читай ошибки компиляции. Там должно было прям на эту строку ругаться